# This page can't be displayed Error

Tags: site-collection, access

I am a Site Collection Administrator on our site. All of a sudden I can't access our SharePoint portal, https://portal..... I get "`This page can't be displayed`" error. I can however access or development site, https://portaldev...
I am the only one with this issue. I can access it from any other computer, so this must be my machine that is causing the problem. One other oddity is when you check my permissions on SharePoint it shows that I only have "Full Control" through a singe SP group I'm in - usually it shows a long list of permissions - none of these are showing! But I still have all the access/permissions of a Site Collection Administrator.

Here's the page I get,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting the web-app by going into IIS. It might be some issue with Web app or some other admin has played with your permissions.

And the thing related to page not opening in one single machine and opening in others is surely a machine issue and not a sharepoint related issue.

Comment: We fixed my access to our portal page by re-imaging my machine. I can now access it but my permissions are still out of whack! Meaning, when I do a Check Permissions on myself it doesn't show the long list of "Allow" accesses the other site admins shows, it just shows one Active Directory group and SharePoint group I am in. The odd thing is that I do have all the permissions of a site collection admin still!

Comment: its because that particular SharePoint group has all the necessary permission. Other permission which other admins are showing are inherited from web app level

Answer (score 0):

for page cannot find issue. Please make sure following things.

- you typed the correct URL.
- check the proxy settings of the Internet Browser
- check the host file, if there is any entry causing it.
- try with different browser on your machine.
- clear the browser cache.

if your permission is via group then it will list the groups, unless they directly grant you permission.